# An Alternative to a Cursor for this Process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that has records in this format:

```
SPECIAL_ID | OTHER_ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP
```

I need to create a new table based off of this, but only get records that are at least 25 minutes apart from the previous one.  The intervals are not consistent. So, if I start with record 1, I need to get the very next record that is at least 25 minutes from record 1's timestamp.  This will be record 2 in the new table.  And then the next record that is 25 minutes after the previous one that was extracted. So, here is an example of info:

```
AAA | 1 | WHATEVER2  | 2016-11-20 00:00:00
BCD | 2 | WHATEVER00 | 2016-11-20 00:02:00
AAA | 3 | WHATEVER01 | 2016-11-20 00:09:00
AAA | 4 | WHATEVER55 | 2016-11-20 00:20:00
XYZ | 5 | WHATEVER   | 2016-11-20 00:24:00
AAA | 6 | WHATEVER11 | 2016-11-20 00:45:00
QRS | 7 | WHATEVER   | 2016-11-20 00:46:00
QRS | 8 | WHATEVER12 | 2016-11-20 00:59:00
AAA | 9 | WHATEVER12 | 2016-11-20 01:02:00
AAA |10 | WHATEVER12 | 2016-11-20 01:17:00
```

And what I am trying to do:

```
AAA | 1 | WHATEVER2  | 2016-11-20 00:00:00
AAA | 6 | WHATEVER11 | 2016-11-20 00:45:00
AAA |10 | WHATEVER12 | 2016-11-20 01:17:00
```

I managed to use a cursor and tested it on a small set of records.  It worked....but I have *millions* of records that need to be analyzed in this way.  A cursor is just asking for trouble, it seems.

Is there a better way to do this?

I am stuck with SQL server 2008, so `lead()` and `lag()` is out of the question.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible (computationally expensive) solution for Sql Server 2008:

In the first step, the first records are determined. At the second step, the query determines the nearest 25-minutes records for each existing record. 
Subsequently (step3), the data records are reduced to the one with the lowest OTHER_ID. Of course, this only works if the field with the OTHER_ID unique and increases synchronously with the time.
For millions of records, the fields used in the query should be indexed and the search restricted.

```
-- test script

SET dateformat ymd

;WITH testdata AS (
  SELECT 'AAA'       AS SPECIAL_ID, 
         1           AS OTHER_ID, 
         'WHATEVER2' AS NAME , 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:00:00') AS [TIMESTAMP]
  UNION SELECT 'BCD' , 2 , 'WHATEVER00' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:02:00')
  UNION SELECT 'AAA' , 3 , 'WHATEVER01' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:02:01')
  UNION SELECT 'AAA' , 4 , 'WHATEVER55' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:20:00')
  UNION SELECT 'XYZ' , 5 , 'WHATEVER'   , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:24:00')
  UNION SELECT 'AAA' , 6 , 'WHATEVER11' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:45:00')
  UNION SELECT 'QRS' , 7 , 'WHATEVER'   , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:46:00')
  UNION SELECT 'QRS' , 8 , 'WHATEVER12' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 00:59:00')
  UNION SELECT 'AAA' , 9 , 'WHATEVER12' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 01:02:00')
  UNION SELECT 'AAA' ,10 , 'WHATEVER12' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 01:17:00')
  UNION SELECT 'QRS' ,11 , 'WHATEVER13' , CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-11-20 01:30:00')
), firstRecord AS (
  SELECT SPECIAL_ID, MIN(OTHER_ID) AS OTHER_ID
    FROM testdata
   GROUP BY SPECIAL_ID
), nextRecord1 AS (
  SELECT I1.SPECIAL_ID, I1.OTHER_ID AS OTHER_ID, MIN(I2.OTHER_ID) AS next_OTHER_ID
    FROM testdata I1
         INNER JOIN testdata I2 
                 ON I1.SPECIAL_ID = I2.SPECIAL_ID 
                AND I1.OTHER_ID < I2.OTHER_ID
                AND I2.[TIMESTAMP] >= DATEADD(minute, 25, I1.[TIMESTAMP])
   GROUP BY I1.SPECIAL_ID, I1.OTHER_ID
), nextRecord2 AS (
  SELECT SPECIAL_ID, MIN(OTHER_ID) AS OTHER_ID, next_OTHER_ID
    FROM nextRecord1
   GROUP BY SPECIAL_ID, next_OTHER_ID
)
SELECT T2.*
  FROM firstRecord T1
       INNER JOIN testdata T2 
               ON T1.OTHER_ID = T2.OTHER_ID
UNION
SELECT T2.*
  FROM nextRecord2 T1
       INNER JOIN testdata T2  
               ON T1.next_OTHER_ID = T2.OTHER_ID
```